# win32_query_Service_status

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to a remote server Win 2003 using a PHP script I have come across from php.net below and returns error 5 which is permissions, the code works great when I query localhost.

Has anyone ever come across this issue before or know a work around? Once I know I can connect I plan to monitor services and then be able to restart them with monitor script.

```
$servicename ="crmskidata"; 
$machine ="crm2011"; 
//print_r (win32_query_Service_status($servicename,$machine)); 

echo  $servicename; 

$sray = win32_query_Service_status($servicename,$machine); 

echo "<br>"; 

print_r ($sray); 

echo "<ul>"; 
echo "<li>Service Type: " .$sray[ServiceType] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>CurrentState: " .$sray[CurrentState] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Controls Accpeted: " .$sray[ControlsAccepted] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Win32 Exit Code: " .$sray[Win32ExitCode] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Service Specific Exit Code: " .$sray[ServiceSpecificExitCode] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Check Point: " .$sray[CheckPoint] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Wait Hint: " .$sray[WaitHint] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Process Id: " .$sray[ProcessId] . "</li>"; 
echo "<li>Service Flags: " .$sray[ServiceFlags] . "</li>";
```

Comment: create php script on server with service status then echo json and get this data by curl. Or temporary disable firewall and check what port are used

Comment: All sorted now thanks for your reply though ;-) I made my web server a local admin on the machine i wanted to connect to and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Added the webservers mavhine name to the local administrators group on the machine i was trying to connect to.